# Stopping SWIG from expanding #if expressions

Tags: swig

I have a case where I need to put a guard on a definition so that it doesn't get included in the SWIG output more than once under certain circumstances.  Unfortunately, SWIG is expanding the #if statement before writing the .cc file.  Here's the situation:

```
%define FOO(BAR)
%{
#if !defined(_##BAR##_DECLARED)
    #define _##BAR##_DECLARED

    // declaration stuff

#endif
%}

// implementation stuff

%enddef
```

SWIG generates `FOO(CLS)` as follows:

```
#if !0
    #define _CLS_DECLARED
/*@SWIG:dummy.swg,46,FOO@*/

    // declaration stuff

/*@SWIG@*/;
#endif

// implementation stuff
```

So the `#if` statement is expanded by SWIG before writing the output (creating the useless `#if !0`), but not the `#define`.  Is there a way to tell SWIG to not to expand the `#if`?

I tried adding an auxiliary macro `GUARD(SYM)` which I've defined in various ways:

```
// Using C-style macros, including !defined()
#define GUARD(SYM) !defined(_##SYM##DECLARED)

// Using C-style macros, excluding !defined()
#define GUARD(SYM) _##SYM##DECLARED)

// Using SWIG-style macros, including !defined()
%define GUARD(SYM) !defined(_##SYM##DECLARED)
%enddef

// Using SWIG-style macros, excluding !defined()
%define GUARD(SYM) _##SYM##DECLARED
%enddef
```

For each of these I've modified the `#if` statement accordingly.  The output is always the same.

In case it's useful, here's the output of `swig -version`:

```
SWIG Version 2.0.8

Compiled with g++ [i386-apple-darwin11.4.2]

Configured options: +pcre

Please see http://www.swig.org for reporting bugs and further information
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want SWIG to pass statements directly into generated file unchanged then put them into 
%{ ..  %}

Yes, its used for delivering *#include* into swig generated output as well.

Comment: Actually, that was a typo.  I am using `%{` and `%}`, please see my edit.